# Responsive layout without media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've just recently learned CSS Grid and am wondering if there's a way to accomplish a particular layout without using media queries or size based breakpoints.

I have a very simple 3 area grid. On large view ports there is a picture which is on the left side of the screen, a title which is to the right of the picture, and some text that describes the image placed underneath the title. The image sets the amount of vertical space that is used.

On mobile it changes to a single vertical column with the title appearing before the image, then the image, then the description.

See the attached picture for a visual description. In the image the box labeled 1 is the image, 2 is the title, and 3 is the description.

I know this can be achieved using media queries and size breakpoints, but I have a feeling there's a CSS Grid or Flex solution that I'm not seeing.

Thanks for your time!

[The desired layouts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p80fC.png)

Comment: The whole point of `grid` is to use `@media` queries to change its layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Grid is made for responsive design and particularaly the use of media queries. I would discourage actively seeking to avoid using media queries - once you get to grips with them they can achieve some great results. The below can be used as a starting point.

```css
.grid {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 3, 180px );
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.grid div:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
.grid div:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat( 6, 150px );
  }
  .grid div:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-row: 2 / 5;
  }
  .grid div:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="grid">
  
  <div></div>
  
  <div></div>
  
  <div></div>
  
</div>
```

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries) breaks down media queries in a simple way that should help to initially get your head around them if you are struggling.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I saw some cool designs that use grid-auto-flow and though I was missing a design concept. Turns out I was wrong.

Thank you for the answer.